# Silverlight application not running on server

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight

I have a .NET application using silverlight.
On page load my control is not being rendered and I get the follwoing error-

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application The remote server returned an error: NotFound.   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, Object state)
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at MultipleUpLoad.Upload_page.GetEventListCallBack(IAsyncResult res)
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClass19.<InvokeGetResponseCallback>b__17(Object state2)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```

Since it is only happening on server it seems to be environment issue. what all should I check?

Below is the screen as seen on my localLeft handside control rendered properly:[image]

Below is how it is rendered (left hand side control not being rendered properly) when deployed on server

[image]

The code for my control-

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="myTaskTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="Auto" >
        <TextBlock Margin="5,5,5,5" Width="175" Height="20" FontSize="11" Text="{Binding EventName}"  />
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="auto">
            <TextBox Margin="5,5,5,1" Width="150"  Height="20" IsReadOnly="true"></TextBox>
            <ProgressBar Margin="1,1,1,1"  Width="150" Height="8"></ProgressBar>
        </StackPanel>
        <Button  VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="5,5,5,5" 
                 Content="Upload" Width="80" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="11" Click="uploadBtnClick_EventHandler" Tag="{Binding EventName}"></Button>
        <!--<CheckBox Margin="5,5,5,5" VerticalAlignment="Top" ></CheckBox>-->
        <Ellipse Height="15" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="15" Stroke="LightGray"  StrokeThickness="2"/>
        <Button VerticalContentAlignment="Center" IsEnabled="False" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="5,5,5,5" Content="Edit Mapping" Width="110" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="11" Click="editMapping_click"></Button>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Code behind:

```
 public Upload_page()
    {
        appln = (App)Application.Current;
        UploadDataUri = appln.DeploymentConfigurations["Silverlight_Config_UploadFileURI"];
        LoadDataUri = appln.DeploymentConfigurations["Silverlight_Config_LoadDataURI"];
        UploadUsingWebClientUri = appln.DeploymentConfigurations["Silverlight_Config_UploadUsingWebClientUri"];
        GetEventListUri = appln.DeploymentConfigurations["Silverlight_Config_GetEventListUri"];
        LoginUri = appln.DeploymentConfigurations["Silverlight_Config_LoginUri"];
        InitializeComponent();

  //      filelist = new List<FileInfo>();
        ((TextBox)FindName("dataloadUri")).Text = LoadDataUri;
        ((TextBox)FindName("receiverUri")).Text = UploadDataUri;

        // Initialize EventList
        InitializeEventList();

    }

    public void InitializeEventList()
    {
        HttpWebRequest rq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequestCreator.BrowserHttp.Create(new Uri(GetEventListUri));

        rq.Method = "POST";
        rq.Headers["EventName"] = "GetEventList";

        rq.BeginGetResponse(GetEventListCallBack, rq);

    }
    public void GetEventListCallBack(IAsyncResult res)
    {
        HttpWebRequest rq = (HttpWebRequest)res.AsyncState;
        using (HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)rq.EndGetResponse(res))
        {
            using (Stream dataStream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
                var result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                {

                    var doc = XDocument.Parse(result);
                    var error = (from p in doc.Descendants("Error") select p).ToList();
                    if (error.Count == 0)
                    {
                        eventList = (from p in doc.Descendants("mEvent") select GetEvent(p)).ToList();
                        LayoutRoot.DataContext = eventList;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //redirect to userLogin
                        System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri(LoginUri));
                    }
                }
                                                               );
            }
        }
        //_autoEvent.Set();
```

Comment: `NotFound` is often a serialization issue thrown by the underlying wcf service. Enable svc trace logging and check the log after you get the exception.

Comment: There is no underlying WCF service.:(

Comment: Then how do you make calls to the server? Try enabling it anyway, see this for more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751526(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Can you post your c# code?

Comment: Edited my question to include the code.